# Not working without sonar.language property

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

I am trying to run the sonarqube task in Gradle. If I don't set the `sonar.language` property, it throws the next exception for multiple classes:

```
Exception during analysis of file ...
java.io.IOException: Error while analyzing class ...
```

It seems weird to me because the property has been deprecated. I would run it with the property set to `java`, but I have one Groovy test file that I need to include in it.

Comment: It would help if you [edit]ed your question to include what value you use for `sonar.language` and the language of the file analysis stops on.

Comment: Please add also your Gradle configuration.